# Plotly: changing the colour scale (colour gradient) to a specific range of colour

Tags: r, graph, colors, plotly

How do you change the colour gradient to a specific colour range in Plotly?

Here I have my code to plot a cluster of the stars in 3 dimensional space. The colour of the stars is decided based on the id of each star.

```
p.0000 <- plot_ly(c_0000, x = ~x, y = ~y, z = ~z, 
                  color = ~id, size = 5, 
                  sizes = c(1, 1)) %>%
  add_markers() %>%
  layout(scene = list(xaxis = list(title = 'x', color = 'white'),
                      yaxis = list(title = 'y', color = 'white'),
                      zaxis = list(title = 'z', color = 'white')),
         paper_bgcolor='#222',
         showlegend = FALSE,
         legend=list(color = "white")
  )

p.0000
```

And the output is this.
[image]

As you can see, now the colour range begins from purple and goes up to yellow. But since it's a cluster of stars, I want to set the gradient of the colour of the stars more yellowish.

Does anybody know the solution? Thank you very much!

EDITED:
Here is the head and summary of the c_0000, which has 64000 rows.

```
>head(c_0000)
         x           y          z          vx          vy          vz          m     id    time
1  0.485939060 -0.52435857 -0.5319823  0.46153894 -0.03377579 -0.32276499 1.5625e-05  1    0
2 -0.065960690  0.08084424 -0.2760305 -0.57578009  1.10781500 -0.29340765 1.5625e-05  2    0
3 -0.034809157  0.07679548 -0.3908799 -0.55399138 -0.17386098  0.05925081 1.5625e-05  3    0
4  1.502104500  1.44298320  1.4497470 -0.09026588  0.32661179 -0.31059352 1.5625e-05  4    0
5 -0.009553516  0.53834057 -0.2672637  0.01185465 -0.01187402 -0.40556487 1.5625e-05  5    0
6 -0.356016520 -0.04570535  0.3350056 -0.70900804 -0.64990276  0.39794922 1.5625e-05  6    0


> summary(c_0000)
   x                   y                   z                   vx                   vy           
 Min.   :-4.698981   Min.   :-5.095714   Min.   :-5.015129   Min.   :-1.6192034   Min.   :-1.482613  
 1st Qu.:-0.334822   1st Qu.:-0.336613   1st Qu.:-0.335628   1st Qu.:-0.2697400   1st Qu.:-0.271454  
 Median :-0.000482   Median :-0.000432   Median :-0.003949   Median :-0.0002091   Median : 0.001419  
 Mean   : 0.000000   Mean   : 0.000000   Mean   : 0.000000   Mean   : 0.0000000   Mean   : 0.000000  
 3rd Qu.: 0.334706   3rd Qu.: 0.332101   3rd Qu.: 0.330509   3rd Qu.: 0.2691137   3rd Qu.: 0.270754  
 Max.   : 5.401047   Max.   : 5.680950   Max.   : 4.762590   Max.   : 1.5473192   Max.   : 1.584202  
   vz                   m                   id             time  
 Min.   :-1.6852456   Min.   :1.563e-05   Min.   :    1   Min.   :0  
 1st Qu.:-0.2709821   1st Qu.:1.563e-05   1st Qu.:16001   1st Qu.:0  
 Median : 0.0001771   Median :1.563e-05   Median :32000   Median :0  
 Mean   : 0.0000000   Mean   :1.563e-05   Mean   :32000   Mean   :0  
 3rd Qu.: 0.2700553   3rd Qu.:1.563e-05   3rd Qu.:48000   3rd Qu.:0  
 Max.   : 1.6006814   Max.   :1.563e-05   Max.   :64000   Max.   :0
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to add `colorscale='YlOrRd'` or `colorscale='Hot'` inside `plot_ly()` and see if it works.

Comment: Can you post a minimal number of rows of `c_0000`?

Comment: colors = 'YlOrRd' worked perfectly, instead of colorscale. But thank you for giving me a hint!